# Why am I initializing values then the compiler still gets an error C# ( NETCore )

Tags: c#

This is my mistake, I hope everybody help me

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwA25.png]

Comment: Can you paste the code instead of an image?

Answer (score 4):

Earlier in your method, you declare a variable:

```
int i;
```

Then, your error appears on this line:

```
Parallel.For(0, MXNum, i =>
```

This is because `i =>` implicitly creates a new variable named `i`. You already declared a variable named `i` earlier in the method, so one of the variables must have a different name in order for the compiler to succeed.